# How to handle spaces in search term

Tags: ios, string, search, space

I am implementing a search using the following code snippet.

```
-(void)getData:(NSString *)searchString
{
    //Search string is the string the user keys in as keywords for the search. In this case I am testing with the keywords "epic headline"
    searchString = [searchString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *resourcePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/sm/search?limit=100&term=%@&types[]=users&types[]=questions&types[]=topics",searchString];

    [self sendRequests:resourcePath];
}


//URL sent to server as a result
send Request /sm/search?limit=100&term=epic headline&types[]=users&types[]=questions&types[]=topics
```

My search is not working as it is unable to handle the space between 'epic' and 'headline'. How can I modify the search term so that the spacing can be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding on the result string to encode space characters as requiredby the rules of URLs.